# Nested Fabric Connections

Tags: python, django, ssh, fabric

The scenario is our production servers are sitting in a private subnet with a NAT instance in front of them to allow maintenance via SSH. Currently we connect to the NAT instance via SSH then via SSH from there to the respective server.

What I would like to do is run deployment tasks from my machine using the NAT as a proxy without uploading the codebase to the NAT instance. Is this possible with Fabric or am I just going to end up in a world of pain?

**EDIT**
Just to follow up on this, as @Morgan suggested, the gateway option will indeed fix this issue.

For a bit of completeness, in my fabfile.py:

```
def setup_connections():
    """
    This should be called as the first task in all calls in order to setup the correct connections
    e.g. fab setup_connections task1 task2...
    """
    env.roledefs = {}

    env.gateway = 'ec2-user@X.X.X.X' # where all the magic happens

    tag_mgr = EC2TagManager(...)

    for role in ['web', 'worker']:
        env.roledefs[role] = ['ubuntu@%s' % ins for ins in
                              tag_mgr.get_instances(instance_attr='private_ip_address', role=role)]


    env.key_filename = '/path/to/server.pem'

@roles('web')
def test_uname_web():
    run('uname -a')
```

I can now run `fab setup_connections test_uname_web` and I can get the uname of my web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have a newer version of Fabric (1.5+) you can try using the gateway options. I've never used it myself, but seems like what you'd want.

Documentation here:

- [env var](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#gateway)
- [cli flag](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/fab.html?highlight=gateway#cmdoption-g)
- [execution model notes](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html?highlight=gateway#leveraging-native-ssh-config-files)
- [original ticket](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/38)

Also if you run into any issues, all of us tend to idle in irc.

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't had a chance to try it out yet. I was chaining my fabric commands so that the proxy (NAT) had a replica fabfile and the local machine's fabfile would connect to the proxy and execute commands from that......which in typing this sounds horrid, but kinda worked. I'd like to use the gateway options however as it seems a lot nicer. Will update once I've investigated further